# Yii join with not in criteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tables as follows :

```
Invoices
---------
id 
job_id
amount


Jobs
----
id
from
time
```

How can i create a yii CDbCriteria to get Jobs which are not in Invoices?

If i have a `HAS_MANY` relation from Jobs to Invoices , how can add this in search function ?

Comment: Did you try till now ?

Comment: You can do with query without using CDbCriteria.

Comment: @kumar_v probably No, otherwise OP have written a query in Question.

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: @tinybyte not exactly , i was looking for a solution with which uses the relation defined in the model class

Comment: I updated my answer, how about this?

Comment: @tinybyte Thanks for your quick response , let me try this out ..
Will let you know the comments in a while ..

Answer (score 2):

A solution with SQL

```
 $items= Yii::app()->db->createCommand( 
               'SELECT * FROM Jobs \
                WHERE Jobs.job_id NOT IN ( \
                           SELECT job_id   \
                           FROM Invoices)')->queryAll();
```

If you really need to use criteria you could try [`addNotInCondition`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addNotInCondition-detail) method (available since v1.1.1).

Answer (score 1):

how about left join?

```
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN Invoices i ON i.job_id = t.id';
$criteria->addCondition('i.job_id IS NULL');
```

or

```
$criteria->with(array('relationName'));
$criteria->addCondition('relationName.id IS NULL');
```

this will select the ones not in invoices table.